# iOS - STOP App Using GPS when its in background - iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to STOP App Using GPS when its in background state in iOS,

I have already implemented the `[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`,

But in iPhone 6s its showing that app using the GPS in status bar notification.

Comment: In which delegate function do you write this code ? "[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]"

Comment: Check if the function is called properly by logging this. NSLog or printf should give more info. Also sometimes iOS shows GPS on status bar for some time even after app is gone to background. Probably you should check until 10 seconds for the OS to refresh.

Comment: Where you use [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] ? please give details code

Comment: which permission did you used alwaysUsed or whenInUse?

Comment: i have used "whenInUse" permission, and used: [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; in applicationDidEnterBackground & applicationWillEnterForeground and when applicationDidBecomeActive i will startupdatinglocation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
CLLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
```

then you will need to stop it as well, using - `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

Please try adding it in your code while using `stopUpdatingLocation`

```
[manager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable])
{
   [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

 [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
```